# "This page can't be displayed error" in IE when logging on as non-admin

Tags: cme

I have installed Tridion 2013 in a Virtual machine. Tridion GUI is accessible when I login in to the machine using Administrator account, but when logged in using normal user account (Windows user) Tridion explorer is not loading and I am getting **This page Can't be displayed** error in IE. I have added the user account in Tridion CMS. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: what happens if you try a different browser (chrome or firefox)? Do you see anything special in your windows event log (check for IIS errors or warnings, or errors or warnings in the tridion eventlog category) ?

Comment: Check the setting of your IE browser in case it is opening properly on other browsers, various security settings might now let you allowed and give you "This Page can't be displayed error" - In other browser you may either get the CME loaded correctly or at least you will get some nice error message - just share that if it is the case

Comment: Hi Harald/Pankaj, I tried with Chrome and now I am able to access Tridion explorer. Thank you so much for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Did you use IE from the server? In that case, could it be that the enhanced security mode of IE was causing this problem?